# Simple Regex help to get me started

Tags: regex

I am trying to come up with a simple regex that will look for the first ':' followed by a unknow number of strings until a '.' is found and return the string in between.

Example

```
test example:IWANTTHISBACK. [8909] test
```

Results

```
IWANTTHISBACK
```

Any help would be a great

Comment: /:(.*?)./ - I am new to regex and am a bit unsure was hoping this would help me understand. @Cylian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

```
(?<=:)([^\.]*?)(?=\.)
```

**Explanation**

```
<!--
(?<=:)([^\.]*?)(?=\.)

Options: case insensitive

Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=:)»
   Match the character “:” literally «:»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([^\.]*?)»
   Match any character that is NOT a . character «[^\.]*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=\.)»
   Match the character “.” literally «\.»
-->
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! Are you able to select the first match only? @ Cylian

Comment: May or may not, it depends on how you're going to implement it.

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to come up with a simple regex that will look for the
>   first ':' followed by a unknow number of strings until a '.' is found
>   and return the string in between.

You basically answered your own question. If you translate this to regex it looks fairly simple:

> for the first ':'

```
:
```

> followed by a unknow number of strings until a '.'

```
[^.]* matches all non dots and stops at first dot.
```

So if you write all this together:

```
:([^.]*)
```

Backreference `$1` will have your string.

Answer (score 0):

In Java

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":([^.]*)\\.");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("test example:IWANTTHISBACK. :abc.[8909] test");
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
IWANTTHISBACK
```